# Searching a specific list using the default search box that comes with list

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have created a SharePoint list by exporting an Excel sheet that has over 30000 rows of names, address...etc. The list looks fine, and it has the default inline search box. I am looking for OOTB solution to expose ONLY the inline search box and  have the users use the search box instead of filtering the list (does not work as it is over the list view threshold). 
In short I would like the users when they click on the list to see only the following:

[image]

The main reason for that, it display the result in an elegent way and I don't want to miss with creating search result and display template. Here is a screen shot when I use the inline search box for the list:

[image]

Note: I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise

Comment: Do you want to show only the search box and not list view table/item rows?

Comment: Yes, I want to show ONLY the search box and no items to force users to use the search box to look for items.

Comment: Surely this is not possible using SharePoint OOTB capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

using PowerShell (or CSOM, or REST API), set the `Filterable` property for each of those `Fields` to `false`, then the User Interface hides the filter controls for those fields.